# Qlikview Combo Chart - Series not aligning with Axis

Tags: charts, qlikview

I have a combo chart that I want to track Actual spending versus Budget over a 3 year period.  The Budget line items are bar charts, the Actuals are displayed by a symbol.  There is only one data point for Actuals, 2020, Budget data is for 2020-2022.  My problem is that Actuals are aligning with 2021, not 2020.  Viewing the data as a straight table, I know my data calculations are correct.  I am not suppressing zeros and the order of expressions (promote, demote) has no effect. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

[Image explaining the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSwQ5.png)

Comment: Could you share some detail about how the expressions are built? Is it a Sum, does it have Set Analysis?

Comment: What Bruno said. Without the expressions the visual is impossible to troubleshoot

Comment: Thanks,

My Dimensions are:  GPID & YR

My expressions are:

Budget =aggr({<GPID = {"=Rank(sum(Heads))<=25"}-{'YW012'}-{'YW00H'}-{'YWLL1'}-{'YWXM1'}>}sum(Heads),[GPID],[YR])

Actuals =aggr({<GPID = {"=Rank(sum(Heads))<=25"}-{'YW012'}-{'YW00H'}-{'YWLL1'}-{'YWXM1'}>}sum(REG_HOURS)/1760,[GPID],[YR])

Comment: On your image, I can see the YR dimension (20,21,22), but nothing with GPID. I can't replicate the issue, could you try to do the AGGR with [GPID] & [YR], to match the dimension you are using?

Comment: I reversed the order of aggr - it did not change the plot.  However, when I promoted the [YR] in Dimensions from (1) GPID (2) YR to (1) YR (2) GPID the Hours aligned to 2020 but the chart lost context because it wasn't clear what GPID the hours were booked against.